# Oracle-Complex sql view creation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below:

[image]

For each disinct combination of ID and VALUE, I have several steps. For example, For the combination of A and B, I have three steps QC, LC and DR  and so on for C and D. Now, I want a view like below:

[image]

That is, I want a column "OUTPUT" in the view where i have to put the first step after QC for each combination of ID and VALUE. For example, For A and B, first step after QC is LC and so OUTPUT value is LC. For C and D, there is no QC and so OUTPUT value is NA.

Can anyone please help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know the specific order of the steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, tables are inherently unordered.  So, you need a column to specify the ordering.  Let me assume that you have such a column, say `StepOrder` in the table.  If so, then you can do what you want using analytic functions.

The `lead()` in the inner subquery returns the next step.  The `max()` in the next subquery returns the value after `QA`, and the output `max()` spreads the value over all rows with the same `id` and `value`:

```
select id, value, step,
       coalesce(max(qa_next) over (partition by id, value), 'NA') as "Output"
from (select t.*,
             max(case when step = 'QA' then nextstep end) over (partition by id, value) as qa_next
      from (select t.*,
                   lead(step) over (partition by id, value order by StepOrder) as nextStep
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
```